# Joining the elements of a list with a separator

Tags: python

I have a python list,

```
   L = [946, 947, 948, 949, 950, 952, 953, 954]
```

How do I print its elements as:

```
946,947,948,949,950,952,953,954
```

without a gap but comma separated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `','.join(str(i) for i in L)`. The `','` is the separator, which is a comma. The `str()` is to convert it to string first, because you have to do that explicitly in python.

Comment: Not quite - the elements must be strings, not ints.

Comment: @Tim Argh, strong typing. Thanks!

Comment: In this case, `map` might be more readable: `','.join(map(str,L))`

Comment: @ssm I think it depends on the reader's familiarity with higher-order functions like `map`. Also, in python 2 using `map` will create an unnecessary list.